# Unique image path within Wordpress Mutlisite

Tags: wordpress

I have an image path in the header.php:

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/links.png
```

I want this image to be different depending on which site (within multisite) the visitor is on.

Obv. the URL is unique, so is there a 'place' within the directory structure that is unique to each site where I could place different versions of the image (all called links.png)

ie.

/wp-content/uniqueFolderForEachSite/links.png

I imagine the only way is using php?

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is not possible. anyone? thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I can confirm this is not possible.

A possible way is to target the images using the unique URL that each site will offer.